# Show file download in glimpse

Tags: asp.net-mvc, glimpse

I have an action in a controller which returns a file to download, however this action doesnt show on Glimpse's history.

Is there a way to make it show up?

This is the code:

```
   public ActionResult DownloadCv(string fileName)
        {


            string filepath = string.Format("{0}/{1}", _appSettings.CvsDirectory, fileName);
            const string contentType = "application/msword";

            return File(filepath, contentType, fileName);
        }
```

Comment: As a side note, I've added the following issue to make this case easier in the future - https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues/740.

Comment: The above feature/issue has been completed. This will be in the next release to go out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason its not currently showing up is because of the [content type policy](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/blob/master/source/Glimpse.Core/Policy/ContentTypePolicy.cs) thats in place by default. If you have a look at the following [documentation](http://getglimpse.com/Help/Configuration), you will see the *Content Types* section which describes what needs to be done:

```
<glimpse defaultRuntimePolicy="On" endpointBaseUri="~/Glimpse.axd">
    <runtimePolicies>
      <contentTypes>
        <add contentType="application/msword"/> 
      </contentTypes>
    </runtimePolicies>
</glimpse>
```

The problem you may run into here is that with the way the content type policy is implemented, it returns `RuntimePolicy.On`. This means that the glimpse client will try and embedded in the result. What you actually want is `RuntimePolicy.PersistResults`. So after you add the above `contentType` to the `runtimePolicies` section. I would also create the following and drop it into your project, Glimpse should pick up the rest.

```
public class MsWordContentTypePolicy : IRuntimePolicy 
{  
    public RuntimeEvent ExecuteOn
    {
        get { return RuntimeEvent.EndRequest; }
    }

    public RuntimePolicy Execute(IRuntimePolicyContext policyContext)
    { 
        var contentType = policyContext.RequestMetadata.ResponseContentType.ToLowerInvariant();

        return contentType == "application/msword" ? RuntimePolicy.PersistResults : RuntimePolicy.On; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This has since been incorporated in Glimpse, such that you can just use:

```
<glimpse defaultRuntimePolicy="On" endpointBaseUri="~/Glimpse.axd">
   <runtimePolicies>
     <contentTypes>
       <add contentType="application/msword" runtimePolicy="PersistResults" />
    </contentTypes>
  </runtimePolicies>    
</glimpse>
```